# How to call GrandCentralDispatch properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to load custom data type from my API and display it on my landing page of an iOS app.

As i understand, I should call something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  performSelector(inBackground: #selector(fetchJSON), with: nil)
  let myCustomDataType = //how so I get this back
  tableView.reloadData()
 //...
}
```

Obviously the declaration of fetchJSON should be in another file so I don't fill my Controller up with things it doesn't need to do. However I need this function to return a list of [MyCustomDataType] and display those on my landing page.

```
func fetchJSON() -> [MyCustomDataType] {
  //get api, fetch data, put it in my custom data type list
  return myCustomDataType
}
```

Do I use closures? Create a global [MyCystomDataType]. Or how do I achieve this?
Be mindful of the task being async, since I display table cells kinda like facebook, or instagram news feed page.

Comment: From an async API fetch you don't return data. You pass a closure, and call it, inside the method (fetchJSON), once async task (fetching) is done. Keep in mind that this should be an escaping closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `fetchJSON` loads the data asynchronously you have to add a completion handler

```
func fetchJSON(completion: @escaping ([MyCustomDataType]) -> Void){
    API.fetch { fetchedData in
        completion(fetchedData)
    }
}
```

Then call `fetchJSON` on a background thread and reload the table view on the main thread

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
      self.fetchJSON { data in 
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.myCustomDataType = data
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Popular asynchronous APIs like `URLSession` and `Alamofire` perform their network requests on a background thread implicitly. If you are going to use one of them you can omit the first `async` block.

`performSelector` is an outdated *objective-c-ish* API. Don't use it in Swift

Comment: Your answer is good as usual (voted), but I would add Rob's point that usually you don't have to use GCD to do network calls asynchronously, since URLSession is already asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

`performSelector(inBackground:)` is not GCD. It's a pre-GCD method from OS X 10.5 that you should almost never use. (I don't think I've had a single reason to use it since 10.6 introduced GCD.)

As a rule, you don't need to use GCD directly at all for network requests. URLSessionTask is already asynchronous. See [Fetching Website data into memory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory) for more. As shown there, you often will need to use GCD (`DispatchQueue.main.async`) to *return* data to the UI, but you don't need it to launch the request.

But to your underlying question, the answer is that by the time `viewDidLoad` completes, you won't have the data yet. You need to be able to deal with not having the data, and draw your UI appropriately. When the data shows up, then you can update your UI.

Comment: Didn't know it shouldn't be used, thanks for the link as well! And my UI is fine, I don't think that's the problem. Question is how do I properly get my [MyCustomDataType] back.

Answer (score 2):

As Vadian said (+1), you want to use asynchronous pattern, and using closures is a good pattern. But the question is not just how to hand back data, but in the case of an error, how to report the `Error`, too. We often use [`Result<Success, Failure>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) pattern to accomplish this. E.g. rather than a `[MyCustomDataType]` parameter, it might have a `Result<[MyCustomDataType], Error>` type.

E.g., let's imagine that you are performing your request via `URLSession`. Then you might have a routine like:

```
enum ApiError: Error {
    case networkError(Data?, URLResponse?)
}

func fetchJSON<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest, queue: DispatchQueue = .main, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        // detect and report error
        guard
            error == nil,
            let responseData = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            queue.async {
                completion(.failure(error ?? ApiError.networkError(data, response)))
            }
            return
        }

        // no network error, so let's parse the response
        do {
            let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: responseData)
            queue.async {
                completion(.success(responseObject))
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            queue.async {
                completion(.failure(parseError))
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And to perform a particular request:

```swift
func fetchMyCustomDataTypes(completion: @escaping (Result<[MyCustomDataType], Error>) -> Void) {
    let request: URLRequest = ... // build your request here
    fetchJSON(request) { result in
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

Now, do not get too lost in the details, above, as your implementation might vary (e.g. you could just as easily use Alamofire or whatever). The key point is that we have a completion handler closure that includes a `Swift.Result` parameter by which data or error information will be supplied to the caller.

And now, the caller can act accordingly based upon whether the result was a `success` or a `failure`:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       // make sure to call `super`

    fetchMyCustomDataTypes { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            // handle error here, e.g., report the error in the UI; or at the minimum, during development, just print the error
            print(error)
    
        case .success(let objects):
            // use the `[MyCustomDataType]` array, `objects` here, e.g.
            self.objects = objects
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

But the caller doesn't use `performSelector`. Nor does it need to dispatch this network request to a background queue, because network requests are already inherently asynchronous. Just call `fetchJSON` and specify what UI update must happen in the completion handler.